# Uncaught module xhr not found cordova-1.5.0.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth-2.0

I am using phonegap cordova-1.5.0.js and jar.
and using the phonegap-plugins for cordova with jsOAtuh.1.3.3.js

I am getting error message:
"Uncaught module xhr not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.5.0.js"

whenever I am trying to create OAuth Object.

I have the following reference:
https://github.com/bytespider/jsoauth

Here is my code.

```
    var config_google={
        var config_google={
        consumerKey: "{removed}",
        consumerSecret: "{removed}",
        requestTokenUrl: "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope={removed}",
        authorizationUrl:"https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken",
        accessTokenUrl:"https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken"
    };

    function authservice(service){
        //alert(service);
        curfunc = "authservice";
        str_service = service;
        if (service === 'google'){
            oauth = new OAuth(config_google);
        }else if....

    ........
    }
```

I used that code with phonegap-1.4.1.js(previous version) before and it works. and I searched xhr on both 1.4.1 and 1.5.0 they both don't have xhr in it but some commented references. Not exactly sure why changed the 1.5.0 and it will disable the code. and I need to use 1.5.0 is because I need to use the childbrowser plugins.

Would you able to point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hack that got it to work. The require("xhr") at line 802 thinks someone, somewhere registered it, but in logging it, I don't see anyone ever calling Cordova's "define" function to register it.

So, if you comment out those 3 lines of code, it's a quick way to get it to fall back to XMLHttpRequest like so (around line 800 within Request constructor):

```
if (typeof global.Titanium !== 'undefined' && typeof global.Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient != 'undefined') {
    XHR = global.Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
//} else if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
//    // CommonJS require
//    XHR = new require("xhr").XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
// W3C
    XHR = new global.XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Comment: Thank you JesterXL and also Rob G. the original writer of the jsOAuth. You guys rocks. :) Thanks for solving my problem.